# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined(…)

Tags: javascript

```
var newView={
    init:function(){
        this.adminB=document.getElementById('admin');
        this.formC=document.getElementById('containForm');
        this.cancelB=document.getElementById('cancel');
        this.render();
    },
    render:function(){
        this.formC.style.visibility="hidden";//lineONE
        this.adminB.addEventListener('click',function()
        {   
            this.formC.style.visibility="visible";//ERROR OCCURS HERE
        });
        this.cancelB.addEventListener('click',function(){
            this.formC.style.visibility="hidden";
        });
    }
};
```

//In "lineONE" I am not getting any errors. But when I use the same variable again inside the 'click' function, i get this particular error - "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined(…)". 
Please help :)

Comment: `this` isn't the `this` you think `this` is - you need to learn about the minefield `this` is

Comment: @JaromandaX How many puns can cram into one line.....

Comment: `this` inside the click function is totally different from the `this` inside a normal function. Do some research on using `this`.

Comment: Got it corrected using another variable for refernecing 'this'. A single statement was added " var self = this; " And then i used 'self' to refer to 'formC' inside the clcik function